# Программное переключение источников DAO в Factory

Tags: mvc, java

Необходимо создать `DAOFactory`, с помощью которого можно было бы программно переключать источники `DAO` (от них необходимо также предусмотреть передачу `DAOException`). К примеру, для двух источников `DAO (ThingImplXML, ThingImplDataBase)`,  реализующих один `IThingDAO` интерфейс.

Ответ jmu изящен, но вот ещё уточнение: изначально мой вариант похож на Ваш,
но вот если `Factory` реализовать через `Map`-ы (примерно так):

```
public class RepertoireFactory {
private static Map<String, IRepertoireDAO> map = new HashMap<String, IRepertoireDAO>();
static{
    map.put(Constants.XML_IMPL, new RepertoireImplXML());
    map.put(Constants.DB_IMPL, new RepertoireImplDB());
}

public static IRepertoireDAO getRepertoireDAO(String typeImpl) {
    return map.get(typeImpl);
}
```

}

Но возникает вопрос: как быть с `DAOException`, который необходимо передать в вызывающий блок кода?

Comment: Ну и что?)

Comment: обработка ошибок это один из недостатков вашего варианта. кроме того вы сразу же создаете лишние инстансы, - вы сразу же создаете 2 дао обьекта. при чем 1 скорее за все использоватся будет только один из них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
// DAO для аккаунта
interface IAccountDAO {}
class XmlAccountDAO implements IAccountDAO {}
class OracleAccountDAO implements IAccountDAO {}

// DAO для продукта
interface IProductDAO {}
class XmlProductDAO implements IProductDAO {}
class OracleProductDAO implements IProductDAO {}

// фабрика создания дао обьектов
// - интерфейс
interface IDAOFactory {
    public enum Type {XML, ORACLE_DB, MYSQL_DB}

    IAccountDAO getAccountDAO();
    IAccountDAO getAccountDAO(Type type);

    IProductDAO getProductDAO();
    IProductDAO getProductDAO(Type type);

    Type getDefaultType();    
}

// - ее имплементация (которая должна быть еще и синглтоном)
class DAOFactory implements IDAOFactory {
    private final Map<Type, IAccountDAO> accountDAO = new HashMap<Type, IAccountDAO>();

    @Override
    public Type getDefaultType() {
        return Type.XML;
    }

    @Override
    public final IAccountDAO getAccountDAO() {
        return getAccountDAO(getDefaultType());
    }

    @Override
    public IAccountDAO getAccountDAO(Type type) {
        synchronized (accountDAO) {
            if (null == accountDAO.get(type)) {
                accountDAO.put(type, createAccountDAO(type));
            }
        }

        return accountDAO.get(type);
    }

    private IAccountDAO createAccountDAO(Type type) {
        switch (type) {
        case ORACLE_DB:
            return new OracleAccountDAO();
        case XML:
            return new XmlAccountDAO();
        case MYSQL_DB:
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IProductDAO getProductDAO() {
        return getProductDAO(getDefaultType());
    }

    @Override
    public IProductDAO getProductDAO(Type type) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Имхо, такой вариант лучше, чем добавить сеттер в дао объект. Мало ли что туда "запихнут" нерадивые стажеры.

Comment: Спасибо! Обратите внимание на дополнение вопроса, возможно ли через статический блок инициализации Factory передать DAOException?

Comment: ошибку можно обработать прямо в блоке инициализации

Answer (score 1):

[Читаем и радуемся](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html).

А вообще, прежде чем что-то делать, не плохо бы об этом что-нибудь почитать.

Comment: Давно почитали, интересует красивое решение!

Answer (score 0):

`IoC (invertion of control)` контейнеры в помощь, `Spring`, `Guice`, `PicoContainer`. Это то, что могу вспомнить. А так же можно ориентироваться на слова: `Dependency Injection`. В общем, google it!